# Meaning of "it is onto something"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/TZkuQUCUYgM). It is at 49 seconds.

> On earth we deal with flush toilets if that is available, hopefully, to you. You do what you need to do, then you clean yourself up, and then **it is onto** the remainder of the day.

What does "it is onto" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence used by the narrator of the linked video used the phrase "then it's on to the remainder of your day."

In this usage, the phrase means: now that you are done with using the bathroom, you are now able to go on and do whatever else you need to do during the remaining time in the day.

The phrase 'on to' (in this usage) is a short way to say 'moving on to', while the phrase 'the remainder of (whoever's) day' has the meaning of: from this point in time to the end of the current day.

Comment: A point to clarify - 'on to' in this usage is two words.